# app.get callback function does not trigger when use the same url as static file in express

Tags: node.js, express

My server is hosting a static image and I am able to access it in the browser

For example: http://localhost:3000/media/foo.png.

But when I try to get the image with some extra query params, for example
`http://localhost:3000/media/foo.png?var1=1&var2=2`, it will never get into the callback function of app.get('/media') which use the same url as express.static. I wonder if my route wildcard mapping is wrong? or I just can not setup a get method with the same name of static url? how to I solve this.

```
var express = require('express');
app.use('/media', express.static('libs'));
app.get('/media/*', function(req, res) {
  console.log('trigger');
});
```

Comment: Try this `app.all('/media/*', function(req, res) {`?

Answer (score 0):

You need declare `get:media` before `use:static` and check query params:

```
app.get('/media/*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (Object.keys(req.query).length===2) {
    // do something
    console.log(req.query)
    res.end('Well, there are query parameters in the URL...')
  } else {
    next() // Ok, try static
  }
})

app.use('/media', express.static('libs'))
```